# How to use pointers with registers in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm working on a project where I have to debug a "binary bomb" by looking at its assembly code to help us learn about assembly.  This one line is confusing me.

```
cmp    (%esi),%eax
je     80486d1 <main+0xaa>
```

I "solve" the bomb when the code jumps due to the two registers being equal, and lose if it does not.  However, when I set %eax to be the same value as %esi, it does not jump and I fail.  Here's the gdb info registers output immediately before the cmp statement:

```
eax            0x804a048    134520904
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0x1  1
esp            0xffffd7c0   0xffffd7c0
ebp            0xffffd9e8   0xffffd9e8
esi            0x804a048    134520904
edi            0xf7fac5a0   -134560352
eip            0x80486c8    0x80486c8 <main+161>
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
```

The %esi and %eax values are the same, but it's not working as I expected.  The only thing I can imagine is that (%esi) is a pointer? I'm not exactly sure how this works as I am new to assembly and could use some tips as to what is going on here.

Comment: If the data at `(%esi)` was a pointer to itself, then `%esi == %eax` would have made `(%esi) == %eax` true.  i.e. `void*foo = &foo;`, or a circular linked list of length 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  `(%esi)` notation means it is a pointer. The esi register holds effective address.

> I'm not exactly sure how this works

This is kind of a basic knowledge. There is little sense trying to solve complex assembler riddles without getting a hang of basic assembler syntax.

There are many sources on the Net describing the multitude of assembly syntaxes used for x86. You show us what is called "AT&T notation for Intel x86", so here is just one starting point for it: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax